# How can add imagebutton click effect?

Tags: android, onclick, imagebutton

I am working with android. I want to add `onClick()` effect on ImageButton preferably a color around the sides of the button after selected. I had tried with alpha effect.But It looks dark even after get back after click.

How can add ImageButton click effect?

Comment: Can you share your code and screenshots of what you have achieved and what you want?

Answer (score 3):

you can use a selector xml like as follows :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed_yellow"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused_orange"
          android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal_green" />
</selector>
```

and set it as a `background` of your Button.